# Android main activity title image removing

Tags: android, image, manifest, title

I have problem removing this title bar/image:

[image]

I've tried theme change in manifest file

```
(android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoActionBar.Fullscreen"),
```

and I've tried

```
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

aswell, but in both ways, my app "stopped working" right after I ran it. Any sugestions?

Comment: Just try this `@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen` in your `manifest` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.home);
```

Comment: may be you have used these line after "setContentView(R.layout.home);
". Use "setContentView(R.layout.home);" after setting the window feature.

Comment: means if you are using both ways to remove title(in mefifiest & in Activity), use it only one place. but i just checked, it doesn't make any difference. Problem is somewhere else.

Comment: ah, sure, but whether I use first way or second, app keep crashing.. some nullpointerexception, but I have no idea, what pointer should get angry by removing title...

Comment: getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
Try removing this line.
only use:
 requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

Comment: It may be because you are using Action bar in Fragment, but bar has been removed from window.

Comment: hnHeadlinesFragment.setOnHeadlineSelectedListener(this);
this line is creating problem, i think. Use debugger & check what is null?

Comment: null is custom intent, x2, logging, receiver, no idea what that means

Answer (score 1):

in your  your `manifest`changelike this inplace of `NoActionBar` change to `NoTitleBar`

```
<application        
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
```

Answer (score 1):

The second try you made should be made before setting content
Works for me like this

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
setContentView(R.layout.login);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

add it after `super.oncreate`

Answer (score 0):

You'd two ways to do this. As per my comment on your question.

First way is in your `manifest` file -

```
@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen
```

Second way is -

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
setContentView(R.layout.yourLayout);
```

If you're using multiple activities in your app. You've to give the style in first way to every activity. And, if you're choosing second way means, you've to give that `requestWindowFeature` to every `Activity`'s inside and before of `setContentView()`

Hope these helps you and makes you understandable.

Comment: @MilošLukačka You've any exception. Post your logcat.

Comment: 07-19 10:26:49.308: W/dalvikvm(2516): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)

07-19 10:26:49.328: E/AndroidRuntime(2516): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

07-19 10:26:49.328: E/AndroidRuntime(2516): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{sk.ecopress.hn.android/sk.ecopress.hn.android.HNappActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

when I remove title-remover, no problem is detected

Comment: Post some code. I think the error should be different one. See you've  `NullPointerException`

Comment: yes, I was that exception, but when I remove that windowfeature, everything works fine..

Comment: @MilošLukačka Now you can view you output without that image?

Comment: @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
hnHeadlinesFragment=(HeadlinesFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
R.id.headlines);
hnHeadlinesFragment.setOnHeadlineSelectedListener(this);
int catIndex = savedInstanceState == null ? 0 : savedInstanceState.getInt("catIndex", 0);

Comment: setUpActionBar(true, catIndex);
        
        
        hnHeadlinesFragment.setSelectable(true);
        restoreSelection(savedInstanceState);
    }

Comment: Then, how its working fine for me. [See the manifest file](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/69670844/Dummy.zip)

Comment: @MilošLukačka Did you try my app?

Comment: your app is working fine, my manifest is nearly the same, but the app still keep crashing..

Comment: Just keep that style in manifest only. Don't assume the `requestWindowfeature` method in your oncreate..

Comment: I know that I can't use both. But whether I use one or the second way, it keep crashing

Comment: Just debug your app step-by-step from your `onCreate()`

Comment: null are custom intent, x2, logging, receiver, no idea what that means